# How to copy Timeshift file into usb Linux Mint

Tags: usb, backup

I have recently upgraded from "python 3.6.8" to "python 3.7.3" . I have also installed sublime text editor. When I open my laptop, it is booting fine ("LinuxMint19.2"). The problem is when I type my password to enter my computer and I am logging in to my Desktop, there is no GUI. There isn't a toolbar, a background image. It just shows me the desktop icons. When I open the "Computer" folder it doesn't have the (Close, Minimize) buttons. The C+Alt+T command to open Terminal doesn't work. I cannot open Terminal.
I want to go back the time using timeshift, but because I can't open any program without GUI or Terminal, I can't open the timeshift program. I want to copy the date file I want to boot my pc to my usb. But I can't. It keeps showing me an error that I don't have the permission.
What should I do?

**Thank you**

That's how it looks: [enter image 
                      description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qcIl.jpg) , 
                      [enter image description 
                      here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP8a9.jpg)

Comment: Can you open a CLI login with Ctrl-Alt-F1?

Comment: No, I can't. I need my laptop so I guess I'll try to save as many files as I can and then I'll format my disk.
Thank you for your time :)